# Replace value based on two variables and two datasets in R

Tags: r, dataset

I need to replace a value in df1 with a value in df2 based on two variables in df1.

The 'linking variable' in df1 is called `VacancyId` and in df2 `reference`. In df1 the observations have multiple rows and I only need to select one of them. This row that needs to have a replacement, is indicated by the factorlevel which has `(Recruitz)` in its name in the variable `VacancyBankName`. The posibilities are:

- Google Recruitment (Recruitz)
- Social Media Campagne (Recruitz)
- Instagram Campagne (Recruitz)
- Social Media Campagne + (Recruitz)
- Facebook & Twitter Campagne (Recruitz)
- Google Recruitment (Recruitz)
- Google Recruitment Plus (Recruitz)
- Facebook - Adwords campagne (Recruitz)

`df1 = d.9weeks`

`df2 = recruitz`

Some data to make more sense:

```
head(d.9weeks[,c(1,12,16)],15)
VacancyId                 VacancyBankName  ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount
57820                     Monsterboard                                31
57820                     Facebook - Adwords campagne (Recruitz)      387
57822                     Monsterboard                                1
57871                     Monsterboard                                228
57818                     LinkedIn (Jobportal)                        0
57822                     Stepstone                                   3
57822                     LinkedIn (Jobportal)                        1
57871                     LinkedIn (Jobportal)                        2
57818                     Monsterboard                                76
57820                     ICTerGezocht                                0
57871                     Social Media Campagne (Recruitz)            376
57871                     Stepstone                                   56
57820                     Stepstone                                   92
57820                     LinkedIn (Jobportal)                        2
57775                     Intermediair Premium                        9
57775                     LinkedIn (Jobportal)                        0


head(recruitz[,c(2,3)], 20)
reference clicks
57871     326
57820     75
73823    105
73826    114
73785     99
73857     30
73845    177
73944     64
73851      6
73941    114
73902    132
73959    115
73946    189
73962     74
73979     93
73947    152
74006    134
73982    207
74033     60
74022     97
```

So if:
`recruitz$reference == d.9weeks$VacancyId` AND `d.9weeks$VacancyBankName == '... (Recruitz)'`

THEN `d.9weeks$ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount <- recruitz$clicks`

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to merge the 2 `df` together first, and then do an `ifelse` statement using `data.table`. So

`library(data.table)`

`df_final <- as.data.table(merge(df1,df2[,.(VacancyId=reference,clicks)],by="VacancyId"))
df_final[,ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount:=ifelse(VacancyBankName==...)]`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If I merge, I lose a lot of data because it only takes the observations that match. There are way more observations that do not have any recruitz data then observations that do have recruitz data. Do you have a suggestion that bypasses this?

Comment: Yes, `?merge`, there are options `all.x`, `all.y`, `all`, which means (respectively) that keep all rows for `x` ( first argument), all rows for `y` ( second argument) and all for both

Comment: Ok I used this to mark the recruitz data in df1 `d.9weeks$Social <- 0`
`d.9weeks$Social[grep('(Recruitz)', d.9weeks$VacancyBankName)] <- 1`

and `f_final <- as.data.table(merge(x = d.9weeks, y = recruitz,by.x ="VacancyId", by.y = 'reference', all = T))`

to merge the datasets.

But when I do this: `ifelse(df_final$Social == 1, df_final$ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount <- df_final$clicks, df_final$ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount)` it just returns NA

Comment: try using the `:=` notation from the `data.table`, like this `df_final[,ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount:=ifelse(Social==1,clicks,ViewsByVacancyBankAndVacancyCount)]`.